# Getting capital O from getchar when pressing home or end

Tags: c, linux, getchar

I'm using this in my C code:

```
system("stty -echo -icanon");
```

This is part of a homework assignment, but this particular part is something I'm working on beyond the requirements of the assignment.

We're implementing a shell, and we've been given a bunch of code to start with. The code doesn't use ncurses (which I'd use if I could) and changing that would require rewriting a lot of the provided code.

When I press my <kbd>HOME</kbd> or <kbd>END</kbd> key, I get a capital O (that's an o as in Open) and then the <kbd>HOME</kbd> and <kbd>END</kbd> key. I'm using `getchar()` to get the character.

It seems that these are the only two keys that do it, but I'm not sure. I'm not 100% if the provided system function call is the only thing that is different (we also set `stdout` to non-blocking, but that shouldn't matter).

I'm really confused, and I'd like to implement the END and HOME keys because I use them a lot.

I'm sorry if this isn't a lot of information. I don't know enough about `system` to really understand what the ramifications of -echo and -icanon are for stty. I've looked at the man page, but I still can't figure it out.

**EDIT**

From Alex Brown's answer, I confirmed that I am getting escaped characters. I have something like the following (in bad pseudo code):

```
while (TRUE) 
    ch = getchar()
    switch (ch)
        case HOME:
        case END:
            don't print anything...
            break

        default:
            printf(ch);
            break
```

So it's printing out the O from the escape sequence, but not the [ (I have `0x48` for <kbd>HOME</kbd> and `0x46` for <kbd>END</kbd>). Still stumped on how to get the real keycode...

Comment: On many terminals, the HOME and END keys emit escape sequences and not a single character.

Comment: Since you're using `stty`, you're probably on a Unix-like system, and it may well be Linux, but you should probably say because what you're doing (dealing with) is very system-specific.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yup, I'm on Linux running Bash. My terminal reports $TERM as `xterm`, but it's actually gnome terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a console application, the keys such as <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> are usually transmitted as an escape sequence.  The exact sequence depends on the terminal program you are using and how it is configured.  The information is traditionally stored in termcap/terminfo, and ncurses looks it up from there based on your terminal type.

Gnome Terminal sends:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> (`0x1b 0x4f 0x48`) for <kbd>Home</kbd> and
- <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> (`0x1b 0x4f 0x46`) for <kbd>End</kbd>.

KDE Konsole and xterm send:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> (`0x1b 0x5b 0x48`) for <kbd>Home</kbd> and
- <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> (`0x1b 0x5b 0x46`) for <kbd>End</kbd>.

If you read an <kbd>ESC</kbd> character followed by <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>, you will need to read an additional character in order to determine which key was pressed.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it gives examples for Gnome/KDE. I wasn't aware of this. Thanks! I wish I could use ncurses...

Answer (score 1):

Many meta characters (such as arrow keys, function keys, and home, end etc) are received by the terminal (and hence your application), as escaped characters - the escape code followed by one or more byte values.  Since each byte is received by a separate get char call, this is likely to be what you are experiencing.  I don't know why you are seeing the escape character as 'O'.

Comment: Hrm, that makes sense. I'm probably getting something like [O. I noticed [A for one of the arrow keys. Do you by chance know of a way to differentiate a HOME key from the escape sequence? Something like getting the keycode instead of two characters? I guess I may need to do some escape code handling...

Comment: The escape character sometimes appears as `[`, and the bytes following the escape character are often printable (like O).  Sounds like you have found your problem.

Comment: The `[` is probably preceded by an escape character, and you are seeing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: There is no distinction between the <kbd>Home</kbd> key and the sequence of characters it generates -- it does not have a single unique character code. If you can, you should try using the readline library for input -- it'll handle this all for you.

Comment: Interesting @duskwuff, but then how do international keyboards work?

Comment: Keys which correspond to non-ASCII characters typically generate the UTF-8 sequence (or byte in the local charset) which corresponds to them. Terminal support for non-ASCII text is flaky on the whole, though -- for instance, I don't think anyone's ever specified how RTL languages work in a terminal.

Comment: I disagree-international keyboards can be configured in software so that applications see different characters or codes depending upon the locale.

Comment: @AlexBrown This question is on a different level. Keyboards issue key codes, the keyboard driver converts keys and key combinations into characters and special key events and the terminal converts the latter into escape sequences.